# asp.net mvc returning view with id from post request

Tags: rest, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a page with forms and inputs. And I want to perform something like delete to a record, so I have a submit button and post the id of the record to a confirmation page.

But the confirmation page wouldn't be REST since I'm using post. how to give the url the id of the record?

I can't use link because the id of the records depends on input

Comment: Please provide more info, e.g. your existing code and point out exactly where and what you need help with.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript. jQuery would be my choice